# How to properly set up datepicker attached to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker, django-grappelli

I am currently working on a Django project using Grappelli and I am trying to create a page that mimics a standard change form. The page is not based on any model, so I am simply adding in all the fields myself. However, I am having trouble using the datepicker. Whenever I click the button that is supposed to show the calendar, nothing happens. I am sure I am simply not including something important.

Here is my current code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="grp-content-container">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <fieldset class="module grp-module">
                    <div class="form-row grp-row grp-cells-1 dob">
                        <div class="field-box l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
                            <div class="c-1">
                                <label class="required" for="dob">Birthday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="c-2">
                                <p class="datetime">
                                    <input class="vDateField hasDatepicker" type="text" id="dob" name="dob">
                                    <button id="dob-button" type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the javascripts block, I had attempted to add in the datepicker source functionality as taken from this website http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, but that did not seem to have any effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it before couple of times and want to tell that with `grappelli` it works almost out of the box.

The point of interest:

`grappelli.js` with this lines:

```
var dateFields = $("input[class*='vDateField']:not([id*='__prefix__'])");
dateFields.datepicker(options);
```

And `grappelli.reinitDateTimeFields` function which reinits this.

So basically all you have to do is to put `vDateField` or/and `vTimeField` class to your input field and make sure that `grappelli.js` loaded properly and `grappelli.initDateAndTimePicker()` being called when document is ready. Then buttons with datepicker should load themselves automatically.

You can be sure that `grappelli.initDateAndTimePicker()` being called as any other JS-file: just put `debugger;` somewhere in `initDateAndTimePicker` constructor in grappelli.js and then it must pause in your js-inspector.

Hope that'll help, it works for me.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. If you check out the code, I do have vDateField in my desired input and the calendar shows up as a button. The issue is when I click the calendar, nothing happens. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: I think that your custom added button can conflict with auto added one. Also check if `DateTimeShortcuts.dismissCalendar` was called and closes your calendar before you can see it. And also do you have an errors in your inspector?

Comment: Nope, no errors just no response. When I comment out the button, the calendar button disappears, it should appear automatically?

Comment: Be sure that grappelli.js is loaded and grappelli.initDateAndTimePicker() being called on document.ready. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: grapellii.js is loading, but how would I make sure grappelli.initDateAndTimePicker() is being called on document.ready

Comment: As any other JS-file: just put `debugger;` somewhere in `initDateAndTimePicker` constructor in grappelli.js and then it must pause in your js-inspector. I'll put that in answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea what I did wrong, but with your debugging help somehow it fixed itself! This is good advice for anyone having a similar issue